# Для каких бинов имеет смысл конфигурировать ленивую загрузку?

Tags: spring

Для каких бинов в spring имеет смысл конфигурировать ленивую загрузку?

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас есть компоненты, которые "дорого" инстанцировать и которые нужны только в редких случаях использования, то их имеет смысл помечать "ленивыми". Например, компонент обеспечивает запуск Большого Адронного Коллайдера.

Comment: но в таком случае существенно увеличится время обработки первого запроса, оперирующего этим бином, если мы говорим о web приложении и singleton scope?

Comment: Оно увеличиться на время нужное для инстанциации компонента. Но если у вас данный компонент используется редко, то для остальных запросов время уменьшиться. В веб приложении ленивая загрузка на мой взгляд не имеет смысла.